# What are the differences between Drush 9 and 10

Tags: drush

We are using Drupal 8.8 with **Drush 9**.

What are the main risks and benefits of upgrading to **Drush 10**?

The [official release description](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/tag/10.0.0) is rather vague.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the difference here https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/compare/9.7.1...10.0.0

As you can see, they are mostly fixes and improvements.

There are also some compatibility changes:

> [image]
>   <sub>Source: https://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/</sub>

As long as you're using PHP 7.1+ there is no risk. The benefit is that it will still work once Drupal 9 comes out later this year.